# Killing GenServer from inside

Tags: elixir

Consider such simple GenServer module:

```
defmodule Crap do
  use GenServer

  ... #All the needed crap

  def handle_info(:kill_me_pls, state) do
    GenServer.stop(self)
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def terminate(_, state) do
    IO.inspect "Look! I'm dead."
  end

end
```

And consider putting these expressions into the repl:

```
{:ok, pid} = Crap.start_link

send_message_to_that_pid
```

And this is where my conceirns start because `Process.alive? pid` returns true, but process is not responsive and `terminate` isn't being called, although if I call `GenServer.stop(pid)` called in repl on 'clean' process (that had not receive kill message) kills it properly. If stop called on process that received :kill_me_pls message hungs up the repl.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The correct way to stop a GenServer "from inside" is to return a `{:stop, reason, new_state}` value from `handle_*` or `{:stop, reason, reply, new_state}` from `handle_call`. The reason your code fails is that calling `GenServer.stop` sends a special message to the GenServer, and since a GenServer is a single process and currently in `handle_info`, it cannot respond to the `stop` call, so your process hangs / creates a deadlock.

Here's the correct way:

```
def handle_info(:kill_me_pls, state) do
  {:stop, :normal, state}
end
```

You can read more about the possible return values, check out the text under the headings `Return values` in the  [documentation of GenServer](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/GenServer.html).

Demo:

```
iex(1)> defmodule Crap do
...(1)>   use GenServer
...(1)>
...(1)>   def handle_info(:kill_me_pls, state) do
...(1)>     {:stop, :normal, state}
...(1)>   end
...(1)>
...(1)>   def terminate(_, state) do
...(1)>     IO.inspect "Look! I'm dead."
...(1)>   end
...(1)> end
iex(2)> {:ok, pid} = GenServer.start Crap, []
{:ok, #PID<0.98.0>}
iex(3)> send(pid, :kill_me_pls)
"Look! I'm dead."
:kill_me_pls
iex(4)> Process.alive?(pid)
false
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the link is dead and that the documentation of the exit codes is in the Supervisor documentation. Furthermore, if you want any child processes to stop as well then you would return `{:stop, :shutdown, state}`